# How to pass a python class instance to another class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to pass an instance of the `ConfigParser` class to another class that will read parameters from a "config.ini" file. However, I am getting an error `__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. The relevant part of the program files are as follows:

`mavlink.py`

```
class Mavlink():
    def __init__(self, config) -> None:

        self.cam_power_channel = config['RC_CHANNEL']['cam_power_channel']
        self.cam_record_channel = config['RC_CHANNEL']['cam_record_channel']
```

`run.py`

```
import configparser
from mavlink import Mavlink

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

def main():

    try:
        mavlink = Mavlink(config)

    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
        sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

`traceback`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/run.py", line 21, in main
    mavlink = Mavlink(config)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Note: Please revise the question if needed.

Comment: We need to see the *full traceback message* in order to know where the problem occurred.  Any chance that you'd simply forgotten to save your most recent changes to mavlink.py?

Comment: Hi @jasonharper, I saved the `mavlink.py` properly. The full traceback was `__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. I tried to debug the code; however, I could not step into the `mavlink = Mavlink(config)`. I suppose the problem with the Mavlink constructor.  `Super().__init()` can be used in some way, but I'm not sure how in this case.

Comment: No, that is *not* the full traceback - it will consist of multiple lines, including excerpts from the code.

Comment: I have added full traceback in the question, please check.

Comment: Assuming you're using CPython, try deleting the `mavlink.pyc` file, or `__pycache__` directory, and running it again. If that still fails, what happens if you call `Mavlink()` with no arguments?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Please make a [mre].

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another mavlink.py somewhere else?

Comment: Hi @kaya3, I tried to run the program after deleting __pycache__ , but still the same traceback. In the first Mavlink() implementation, there were constant values for `self.cam_power_channel` and  `self.cam_record_channel`, respectively; and it was working fine. Now I am planning to read the values from `config.ini` file.